# Outgoing calls minute reminder

Tags: notifications, tasker

I'd like to have this feature on outgoing calls:
- first vibrate (or beep) after 45 seconds call answered;
- then vibrate (or beep) after every other minute (1.45, 2.45, 3.45 ...)

I created this task in Tasker:
1. wait 45 seconds;
2. vibrate time 50;
3. wait 1 minute;
4. goto action 2;
and put in context: call outgoing.

It kinda works but has a few shortcomings:
- timer starts just after phone number is dialed, not when call answered;
- task keeps going on after call is terminated, need to manually stop it.

I tried with an exit task with an explicit stop action but did not work.
I read about AutoNotification plugin intercept feature but did not understand.

Comment: Any good reasons you don't want to go for a ready-made solution? It appears that [Call Duration Notification](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amanzag.calltimealarm) comes close to your goal. There are also some related apps here: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=call+time+duration

Comment: Do you have root access? Which Android version and device are you using?

Comment: Apart from that, it comes very close to a built-in feature (not sure whether that's stock/AOSP or a CyanogenMod addition). All my phones (all running CM) have that somewhere in settings: vibrate when other party picks up, and vibrate all X seconds during outgoing calls. Have you checked whether you might have that as well?

Comment: @Izzy, I think this may be a stock Android feature. I've Android 4.2.1 (non-CM) and I see an option "Minute reminder (at 50s of every minute)" in Dialer Settings. Perhaps, post an answer maybe?

Comment: @Firelord Done. Just cross-checked with my phones: it's even a perfect match here, as it's "at 45s of every minute" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firelord confirmed this for stock Android, you might not need Tasker for that at all – your dialer probably supports this natively:

Open the Dialer, then check its settings. My dialer has there (in German, so don't take my translation literally):

- vibrate when answered (additionally, also when hanging up or there's another incoming call)
- vibrate every minute (15 seconds before it's up)

I'd say that's pretty close to what you're after – just keep the "vibrate when answered" off and tick the "vibrate every minute", and it's even a perfect match. No need for any additional app, if that's all :)